# Subtract values in one dataframe from another

Tags: r, dataframe

I have two data frames: (these are shortened versions of them)

A

```
    Link    VU  U   P
1   DVH1    7   1   37
2   DVH2    7   0   38
3   DVH3    10  1   35
```

B

```
    Link    VU  U   P
1   DVH1    2   0   15
2   DVH2    4   0   14
3   DVH3    0   0   5
```

I want to substract the values in data frame B from those in A based on their location. So for example:
For DVH1, VU would be 7-2 (or 5), and the resulting data frame would look like:

```
    Link    VU  U   P
1   DVH1    5   1   22
2   DVH2    3   0   24
3   DVH3    10  1   30
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use this:

```
within(merge(A,B,by="Link"), {
    VU <- VU.x - VU.y
    U <- U.x - U.y
    P <- P.x - P.y
})[,c("Link","VU","U","P")]
```

EDIT: Bonus: if there are too many paired columns (not just VU, U  and P) you can use this:

```
M <- merge(A,B,by="Link")

S <- M[,grepl("*\\.x$",names(M))] - M[,grepl("*\\.y$",names(M))]

cbind(M[,1,drop=FALSE],S)

#  Link VU.x U.x P.x
#1 DVH1    5   1  22
#2 DVH2    3   0  24
#3 DVH3   10   1  30
```

Comment: Probably the safest method in case `A$Link` and `B$Link` aren't identical. If they were assured to always be the same then `data.frame(Link=A$Link,A[2:4]-B[2:4])` would be sufficient.

Answer (score 11):

A faster way than `merge` (most likely) is to just make sure the second `data.frame` is in the same row and column order as the first and subtract them from each other:

```
z <- names(A)[-1]
cbind(A[1], A[z] - B[match(A$Link, B$Link), z])
#   Link VU U  P
# 1 DVH1  5 1 22
# 2 DVH2  3 0 24
# 3 DVH3 10 1 30
```

---

Here's some sample data:

```
A <- structure(list(Link = c("DVH1", "DVH2", "DVH3"), VU = c(7L, 7L, 
10L), U = c(1L, 0L, 1L), P = c(37L, 38L, 35L)), .Names = c("Link", 
"VU", "U", "P"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3"))

B <- structure(list(Link = c("DVH1", "DVH3", "DVH2"), P = c(15L, 5L, 
14L), U = c(0L, 0L, 0L), VU = c(2L, 0L, 4L)), .Names = c("Link", 
"P", "U", "VU"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "3", "2"))
```

Comment: Getting the two data frames in the same order is the hard part, and part of why merge is slow (the other part is the horrendously naive implementation)

Answer (score 0):

If the values of the two data frames are in the same position, and the columns have the same names, then `merge()` is not necessary anymore:

```r
## provide the sample data
df1 <- tibble::tibble(
    Link = c("DVH1", "DVH2", "DVH3"),
    VU = c(7,7,10),
    U = c(1,0,1),
    P = c(37, 38, 35)
)

df2 <- tibble::tibble(
    Link = c("DVH1", "DVH2", "DVH3"),
    VU = c(2,4,0),
    U = c(0, 0, 0),
    P = c(15, 14, 5)
)

df1
#> # A tibble: 3 × 4
#>   Link     VU     U     P
#>   <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 DVH1      7     1    37
#> 2 DVH2      7     0    38
#> 3 DVH3     10     1    35

df2
#> # A tibble: 3 × 4
#>   Link     VU     U     P
#>   <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 DVH1      2     0    15
#> 2 DVH2      4     0    14
#> 3 DVH3      0     0     5

## subtract df2 from df1
df3 <- df1[, 2:4] - df2[, 2:4]
dplyr::bind_cols(df1[, 1], df3)
#> # A tibble: 3 × 4
#>   Link     VU     U     P
#>   <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 DVH1      5     1    22
#> 2 DVH2      3     0    24
#> 3 DVH3     10     1    30
```

<sup>Created on 2024-02-22 with [reprex v2.1.0](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>