# R - subtracting multiple columns from multiple columns with 2 data frames

Tags: r, dataframe

I have two dataframes as below:

```
> head(VN.GRACE.Int, 4)
 DecimDate        CSR         GFZ        JPL
1  2003.000 12.1465164  5.50259937 15.7402752
2  2003.083  1.8492431  0.27744418  3.4811423
3  2003.167  1.5168512 -0.06333961  1.7962201
4  2003.250 -0.2355813  6.16296554  0.7215013

> head(VN.GLDAS, 4)
   Decim_Date NOAH_SManom CLM_SManom VIC_SManom SM_Month_Mean
1   2003.000   3.0596372  0.4023805 -0.2175665      1.081484
2   2003.083  -1.4459928 -1.0255955 -3.1338024     -1.868464
3   2003.167  -3.9945788 -1.4646734 -4.2052981     -3.221517
4   2003.250  -0.9737429  0.4213161 -1.0537822     -0.535403
```

EDIT: The names below (UN.GRACE.Int and UN.GLDAS) are the names of the two dataframes above. Have added an example of what the final data frame will look like.

I want to subtract columns [,2:5] in VN.GLDAS data frame from EACH of the columns [,2:4] in UN.GRACE.Int and put the results in a separate data frame (new data frame will have 12 columns) as below:

```
EXAMPLE <- data.frame(CSR_NOAH=numeric(), CSR_CLM=numeric(), CSR_VIC=numeric(), CSR_SM_Anom=numeric(),
       GFZ_NOAH=numeric(), GFZ_CLM=numeric(), GFZ_VIC=numeric(), GFZ_SM_Anom=numeric(),
       JPL_NOAH=numeric(), JPL_CLM=numeric(), JPL_VIC=numeric(), JPL_SM_Anom=numeric())
```

I've looked into 'sweep' as suggested in another post, but am not sure whether my query would be better suited using a for loop, which I'm a novice at. Also looked at [subtracting values in one data frame from another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18708395/subtracting-values-in-one-data-frame-from-another) but doesn't answer my query I don't believe - Thanks in advance

Comment: It will help if you'll provde desired output

Comment: @David Arenburg - Have now edited the question to reflect your queries (hopefully)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 res <- cbind(VN.GRACE.Int[,1,drop=F],
   do.call(cbind,lapply(VN.GLDAS[,2:5], 
      function(x) VN.GRACE.Int[,2:4]-x)))

 dim(res)
 #[1]  4 13
```

Comment: Brilliant is the exact word do describe almost all @akruns answers

Comment: @David Arenburg.  Similar questions I had seen in the past, so it is only an act of remembering the methods used before.  Speaking of brilliance, I wouldn't have come up with a solution like yours in <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24906346/if-function-in-r/24906550#24906550>

Comment: @akrun, actually this is a silly solution which I was considering not posting at all as it is inefficient, The only reason I did post it is because it looked more compact than the rest